# Trying to refactor this FileStream .NET code

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, stream, refactoring

I've got the following `Stream` code . and I feel that it's really old and ugly and that there should be a cleaner way to do this.

```
// Write the current chunk to the stream.
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(tempPath, currentChunk == 0 ? 
                                                     FileMode.Create : 
                                                     FileMode.Append))
{
    var buffer = new byte[uploadedFile.Length];
    uploadedFile.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
```

What is it doing?

I upload a file in *chunks*. So we either create a new file (when we're at the first chunk, ie chunk == 0) .. or we append the chunk data to an existing file.

I feel that the 3 lines are obsolete and there's a better method that's available to be used.

Yes / No / Maybe?

---

EDIT: .NET 4.0 is fine by me :)

Comment: If you read the programming reference `FileMode.Append` either appends or creates if the file doesn't exist - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode.aspx basically you don't need that inline iif?

Comment: Damn nabbit! Of course! how did i forget that :( :blush:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Might `Stream.CopyTo` work for you?

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.copyto.aspx

For what it's worth, though, I don't think this API existed until .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the `File` class *(System.IO)* which provides static methods for messing about with files; so your whole block of code could become this:

```
File.AppendAllText(path, contentToAppend);
```

There are other methods like `WriteAllBytes(...)`, `WriteAllText(...)`, or `ReadAllText(...)`

For reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx